# Download file which name is dot character

Tags: php, php-7

I have this script for downloading file:

```
     if (file_exists($full_path)) {

        // get mime type
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);  
        $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $full_path);
        finfo_close($finfo);

        // get extension
        $ext = pathinfo( $full_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );  

        $file_name = "here is uploaded file's original name";

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'.'.$ext.'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path));
        readfile($full_path);

     }
```

This works except in case , if file have dot (`.`) as file name.

So, if I have file `..docx`, I can upload this on my server, but when I'm trying to download that file with original name, I'm getting file with name  `docx`  which type is `File` and not `Microsoft word document`.

If try same with regular file names, or some another characters, for example comma, exclamation mark e.t.c, download script works fine and I'm getting real `.docx` file.

What I do wrong ?

Comment: Curious... are files with `.` as the name a common occurrence?

Comment: an option could be to use a filename prefix, and remove it from target filename when downloading it again, or hash the filename, or somehow change it.

Comment: Is the file name in the HTTP header correct, and the browser removes the dots? Or is the content of `$file_name` wrong?

Comment: I *think* Apache servers do not output files beginning with a dot to the browser. see: `.htaccess` the dot marks these files as hidden and unreachable by the browser directly.

Comment: It seems Apache removes leading dots at download? So, If filename is `.bla.txt`, at download I'm getting `bla.txt`

Comment: I've never tried it, but my first hunch would be to `urlencode()` the name or escape the dot.

Comment: @jeroen - tried and not works, also urlencode() will change original file names in certain cases, right ?

Comment: Yes, it would...

Comment: In the ..docx example you mentioned, what does `$file_name` contain and what does it have to do with `$full_path` ? I tested with ..txt on my server but I couldn't reproduce the issue. I used `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($full_path) . '"');` in the Content-Disposition header, and I declared `$full_path` earlier to be `__DIR__ . '/' . $_GET['path']`.